# A simple question on p-adic fields

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

I have asked many question tonight on $p$-adic and I am still confused. So here is a very basic thing I want to know but nobody has cleared this doubt. It might be very silly, but please answer it.

If $\alpha \in Z_p$, then $\alpha=(\alpha_0,\alpha_1......)$, where $\alpha_i \in Z/p^{i+1}Z$  Right?. Now somebody says that $\alpha \equiv 1 \hspace{.2cm} mod \hspace{.09cm}p$. What does it mean? Should I think of $1$ as $(1,0,0,0\ldots.....)$ as $\alpha-1$ is defined only when $1 \in Z_p$, so by $1$ here, book means that it is $(1,0,0\ldots...)$? And then $\alpha \equiv 1 \hspace{.2cm} mod \hspace{.09cm}p$ must mean that   $\alpha_0-1=p.k/pZ=0$ for some $k$ and the rest $\alpha_i \hspace{.3cm}(i \ge 1)$ are just multiples of $p$ like $\alpha_2=p.k_2/p^3Z_p$. Now am i correct, if not please rectify me in easiest language. Please.

Comment: You also need to require that $\alpha_{i+1} \equiv \alpha_i \bmod p^{i+1}$. So $1$ is represented by $(1, 1, 1, \dots)$.

Comment: So whenever a rational integer say $b$ is brought in $p$-adic rings or fields it signifies $(b,b,b\ldots...)$?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't seen any of your other questions, so I'm sorry if this is repetitive.

A $p$-adic integer $a$ isn't just any string of integers $(a_1,a_2,a_3,\cdots)$. The numbers $a_i$ have to be compatible. Each $a_n$ actually determines the numbers before it, i.e. those $a_i$ where $i<n$.

The $a_i$ are in a way better and better approximations of the $p$-adic number $a$ represented by that infinite vector. By analogy with real numbers, it's like representing $\pi$ by the sequence of rationals $(3,3.1,3.14,3.141,\cdots)$.

For the $p$-adics, we have $a_1 \in \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. This is the most crude approximation to a $p$-adic integer. A slightly better approximation would be a number $a_2$ in $\mathbb{Z}/p^2 \mathbb{Z}$ that refines the approximation of $a_1$, in the sense that $a_2 \equiv a_1 \text{ mod } p$. Similarly $a_3 \in \mathbb{Z}/p^3\mathbb{Z}$ would be yet another refinement, and would have to satisfy $a_3 \equiv a_2 \text{ mod } p^2$ (then automatically $a_3 \equiv a_1 \text{ mod }p$).

So when someone says $\alpha \equiv 1$ mod $p$, that means the digit $a_1=1$. Whatever the other digits are, they have to be compatible with each other, and especially they all have to be $1$ modulo $p$ to be compatible with $a_1$.

So here are some examples of representations. The number $1\in \mathbb{Z}_p$ would corresponds to $(1,1,1,\cdots)$. The number $p$ would be $(0,p,p,\cdots)$. The number $p^2+p+1$ would be $(1,p+1,p^2+p+1,p^2+p+1,\cdots)$.

I find it generally much more convenient to work with the base $p$ representation of $p$-adic numbers. Just like any real number can be written as a (possibly) infinite sum of powers of 10, a $p$-adic number can be written as a possibly infinite sum of powers of $p$, except that in this case it's the positive powers that are allowed to go to infinity, since higher powers of $p$ are *smaller* in the $p$-adic norm. This means we can represent a $p$-adic number in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ as a sequence of base-$p$ digits that are possibly infinite to the *left* of the decimal point:

$$ (\cdots b_3 b_2 b_1 b_0.b_{-1} b_{-2} \cdots b_{-n})_p = \sum_{k=-n}^\infty b_k p^k.$$

The integers $\mathbb{Z}_p$ are exactly the ones that don't have digits to the right of the decimal point:

$$ (\cdots b_3 b_2 b_1 b_0)_p = \sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k p^k \in \mathbb{Z}_p.$$

One advantage of this notation is that a normal integer is represented in the ordinary way in base $p$. So for example $51$ as an element of $\mathbb{Z}_5$ in the form above is $(201)_5$, same as its base-$5$ representation.

The relation between the two notations is:

$$a_1 = b_0,\ a_2 = pb_1 +b_0,\ a_3 = p^2 b_2 + p b_1 + b_0 ,\cdots.$$

In other words $a_k$ corresponds to the $k$ most significant digits of the base-$p$ representation.

You can then see that for example $1\in \mathbb{Z}_p$ in vector form will just have $a_k=1$ for all $k$, because the $k$ most significant digits of $1$ in base $p$ will just be 1 again.

Comment: Thanks alot. This is what I was looking for. Great explaination. Finally now I can make some sense out of it. Do you have any reference for the basics and concepts on $p$-adic fields and then gradually relating them to quadratic forms to study hilbert symbols on them.

Comment: The way you have explained me this,  If you could have a look at [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1047346/which-p-adic-fields-contain-these-numbers?noredirect=1#comment2133230_1047346) question here and make it this easy, It will be a huge help as another answer using hensel's lemma is beyond me.

Comment: I always recommend this notation and way of computation.

Comment: @BhaskarVashishth: I would recommend J-P. Serre's *A Course in Arithmetic*. The first part is exactly what you want.

Comment: @Prometheus I know that is in our syllabus, but I do not understand it. Isn't there any easier book?